# How should I put an image within a Tensor by TF2.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to put an image within a blank image, and the codes with numpy are as following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

img_paded = np.full(shape=[100, 100, 3], fill_value=128)  # create a blank image

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (50, 50))

x = 10
y = 45
img_paded[y:y+50, x:x+50, :] = img  # put the image at (x,y)
```

For some reason, I need to do it by Tensorflow 2.1 with the following codes snippet:

```
image_string = open('test.jpg', 'rb').read()  # load image as Tensor
img_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)

img_paded_tf = tf.fill([100, 100, 3], 128)
img_paded_tf[y:y+50, x:x+50, :] = img_tf # put the image at (x,y)
```

But it raises error :

```
TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

How should I resolve it? Thanks

Comment: `converted_tensorflow_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(original_numpy_image)`

Comment: @Vlad, thanks for answer and sorry that I didn't describe my problem well! Is it possible to do it if img is Tensor as well?